# When a media network can't show/say a certain brand/logo/product of a company so they censor/blurr/avoid topic, cause brand didn't bought ad

Tags: expressions

It's simply, that in TV, whenever a logo appears, they censor it, or when a person says a brand name, either they cut it, or bleep it. This is due to the network charges for ads, however in that case they obviously can't charge them.
I'm asking for the english expression. In spanish, at least Argentina, the expression is "chivo publicitario".

Comment: Technically, it's *censorship*. But *blurred out* is a perfectly fine phrase for this particular type of censorship.

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree. I had difficulties finding the right words. Stack Exchange in general requires good writings skills, which i lack. I'm glad at least one person, you, at the moment, understood what the concept is, now, we just need to find a word or expression for it. Censorship seems more general, in a correct way, than blurred, because the media network not only blurres logos, it also puts black rectangle or shape, or obscures in some creative way, such as putting a image/"sprite" over it.

Comment: For slightly different reasons, in the UK, the BBC does this in spirit when the brand is incidental to the content though less obtrusively than by blurring it out - sometimes through euphemism ("the market leader" etc.), sometimes with careful placement of cartons, sometimes with quick panning and no lingering focus... and sometimes with bits of tape. In this instance it's so as not to be seen as endorsing, as the BBC carries no advertising and is perhaps more influential for it. See [here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/editorialguidelines/guidelines/editorial-integrity/product-prominence).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything more specific than censorship, so I guess this humorous term from *TV Tropes* will have to suffice.

> [Product Displacement](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ProductDisplacement): [...] when products or corporate logos turn
>   up incidentally in TV programming without having paid the requisite
>   dues, they will be censored.

Apparently, the process of obscuring brand names is called *"greeking"*.

Related to [Brand X](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrandX), when instead of a regular censorship the producers just make up a brand.

Comment: That's interesting! I'd always thought 'greeking' was specific to the obscuring of body text in layout software like InDesign when you zoom out and it's too small to meaningfully represent... which _does_ seem a rather narrow situation to invent a verb for, in retrospect (and a bit of a waste of a clever coinage at that).

Comment: I found greeking in the wiki article in the section "in the arts", in the same way you point out.